# Running C++ application reacting to outside changes

Tags: c++

I have a C++ application that will be running constantly. It is listening for messages from a wireless module.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct payload {
char node[16];
char message
};

...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  mesh.setNodeID(0);  //irrelevant
  mesh.begin();  //irrelevant

  while(1){
    mesh.update();  //irrelevant
    mesh.DHCP();  //irrelevant

    while(network.available()) {
      struct payload received;
      mesh.read(header, &received, sizeof(received));  //irrelevant
    }

  //below code goes here
}
```

And I want to be able to also send messages from this system.

I am currently reading a line from file:

```
//pseudo code
if (!fileEmpty) {
  line = readLine();
  struct payload send;
  send.node = //splitted line
  send.message = //splitted line
  mesh.write(header, &send, sizeof(send));
```

And I split the line using strtok and assign the parts to a struct.

But there should be a better way. 
I can't split the code for sending in different file (called with arguments) because there is some problem with the wireless module when I am listening and sending messages simultaneously. Assuming I splitted the code in two different files, I can kill the listening program when sending and then run it again, but this seems like a bad way of doing things.
So I am out of ideas.

Comment: You can't constantly read and also send with a single thread, and it sounds like you wouldn't want to use multiple threads. So you need a single loop that reads sometimes and sends sometimes.

Comment: Check to see if your wireless module can be run through a [select statement](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?select). Select will allow you to run all of your file and network IO (and other stuff like timers) from one thread.

Comment: I think that the library I'm using for the wireless module handles this. The above program is working perfectly fine when reading a line from file (it is always listening for messages and sends messages when I write something to the file). But I am wondering if there is a better (more elegant) way to do this, aside from writing a line to a file.

Comment: `And I split the line using strtok` - `But there should be a better way.` Indeed! `strtok` is broken. Among other problems, it's not thread-safe if more than one thread uses it at the same time.